Curve fitting with given data points
For an exercise I have to fit the parameters a, b, c, and d of the following formula (https://i.sstatic.net/YjjTASGx.png)
so that the formula best describes a given data set of temperature and time.
This is my approach (Tried to do the fitting with gaussnewton) so far, but it doesn't work at all:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Laden der gemessenen Temperaturen
_, T_measured = np.genfromtxt("4_temperatures.txt", unpack=True)
t_measured = np.arange(T_measured.shape[0])  # Anzahl der Tage seit der ersten Messung

def T(t, p):
    a, b, c, d = p
    return (a * np.sin((t-b)/c) + d)

def DT(t, p):
    a, b, c, d = p
    return np.array([
        np.sin((t-b)/c),
        -a * (t-b) * np.cos((t-b)/c) / c**2,
        a * np.cos((t-b)/c),
        np.ones_like(t)
    ]).T

def gn(x0, T, DT, tol): #gaussnewton
    x = x0
    for i in range(1000):
        s = np.linalg.lstsq(DT(t_measured, x), T_measured - T(t_measured, x), rcond=None)[0]
        x = x - s
        if np.linalg.norm(s) < tol * np.linalg.norm(x):
            return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p0 = [0.8, -1, 50, 0]  # Startwerte, guess [a, b, c, d]
    p = gn(p0, T, DT, 10**(-14))  # Anpassung des Konvergenzkriteriums
    
    fit = T(t_measured, p)
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(t_measured, T_measured, label='data')
    #plt.plot(t_measured, T(t_measured, p0), label='Anfangsschätzung')
    plt.plot(t_measured, fit, label='bester fit')
    
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel('Tage seit erster Messung')
    plt.ylabel('Temperatur')
    plt.savefig("4_mythenquai.png")
    
    # Ausgabe der Parameter
    print("Startwerte:")
    print("a = {:.3f}".format(p0[0]))
    print("b = {:.3f}".format(p0[1]))
    print("c = {:.3f}".format(p0[2]))
    print("d = {:.3f}".format(p0[3]))
    
    print("\nBeste Anpassung:")
    print("a = {:.3f}".format(p[0]))
    print("b = {:.3f}".format(p[1]))
    print("c = {:.3f}".format(p[2]))
    print("d = {:.3f}".format(p[3]))



I also tried gaussnewton, but the fit looks like this:
very bad fit
The data: enter image description here
The data: https://sharetxt.live/txtstackoverflow
Blockquote

Can you supply your data (and expand on "doesn't make sense"). Incidentally, periodic functions might be better fitted with Fourier methods.

how can I share the data? I tried using wetransfer but I cannot share the link

What does your original data look like, then? Your "bad link" shows a y-axis scale so large that it is impossible to see what the data does. If the data is gathered at equal time intervals and you are expecting it to be periodic then use FFTs.

it looks something like this:
23.04.2007 18
24.04.2007 18.6
25.04.2007 19.2
26.04.2007 18.9
27.04.2007 17.8
28.04.2007 18.2
29.04.2007 19.9
30.04.2007 16.8
01.05.2007 15.6
02.05.2007 14.4
03.05.2007 14.4
04.05.2007 13.4
05.05.2007 11.9
06.05.2007 12.9
07.05.2007 14.4
08.05.2007 16.1
09.05.2007 16.5
10.05.2007 17.2
11.05.2007 17.6
12.05.2007 18.1
13.05.2007 17.8
14.05.2007 16.2
15.05.2007 10.7
16.05.2007 11.4
17.05.2007 10.9
18.05.2007 14.6
19.05.2007 16.9
20.05.2007 20.4
21.05.2007 21.8
22.05.2007 20.3
23.05.2007 21.1
24.05.2007 22.1
25.05.2007 22
etc.

If this is daily temperature data then you know what the period is, so  c=(days in year)/2.pi. If it is a whole number of years then d will be the mean of the data. After that you can make starting estimates of a from the range of the data. Not easy to do more without the actual data to play with. I still think you would be better Fourier-transforming it and taking the dominant frequency component.

The amount of data that you have put in the comment is insufficient to fit any function to. Download the original file and then re-upload it somewhere. Show a graph of JUST the original data in your main post.

Hi sorry, you're right. I just uploaded the txt data with a link and inserted a photo of the graph

How do I get the data from that link? I have no account on sharetxt (nor any intention of getting one). I'm pretty sure I can fit that using Fourier methods, but I'd prefer the data to check.

Hi sorry, I don't know how to share the .txt file. I tried wetransfer but the url is banned

Referring to your code:
Are you sure you have made the correct order for DT?
Considering how you define the initial guess as [a,b,c,d], this should be the same order for DT, but here you are deriving based on [a, c, b, d].
Flipping b and c, will give very weird results.
def DT(t, p):
    a, b, c, d = p
    return np.array([
        np.sin((t-b)/c),
        -a * (t-b) * np.cos((t-b)/c) / c**2,
        a * np.cos((t-b)/c),
        np.ones_like(t)
    ]).T


You can try fitting it from the dominant frequency component (which will presumably be 1/year for your ten years of weather data). See whether the following gives anything sensible.
This takes the discrete Fourier transform for a real variable (numpy.fft.rfft), finds the largest non-zero frequency component and then extracts amplitude and phase from that. Finally, it turns it into your a,b,c,d form.
In the absence of your data you will have to tell me whether or not it works. (It gave a sensible answer for the very short dataset in your comment).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_, T_measured = np.genfromtxt("4_temperatures.txt", unpack=True)     # daily temperature
t = np.arange(T_measured.shape[0])                                   # days from start

N = len( t )
T = t[-1] + t[1]                                                     # effective length of record
dw = 2 * np.pi / T                                                   # frequency step in FFT
ytilde = np.fft.rfft( T_measured )                                   # FFT of a real function

m = 1 + np.argmax( np.abs( ytilde[1:] ) )                            # index of dominant frequency
omega = m * dw                                                       # dominant frequency (equals 1/c)
mean = ytilde[0].real / N                                            # mean offset (=d)
A = 2 * ytilde[m].real / N                                           # coefficients in A.cos() + B.sin()
B = -2 * ytilde[m].imag / N                                          #
amplitude = np.sqrt( A**2 + B**2 )                                   # corresponding coefficients in amplitude/phase-lag
phaselag = np.arctan2( -A, B )                                       #     (amplitude equals a, phaselag = b/c)

a, b, c, d = amplitude, phaselag / omega, 1 / omega, mean
print("a = {:.3f}".format(a))
print("b = {:.3f}".format(b))
print("c = {:.3f}".format(c))
print("d = {:.3f}".format(d))

plt.plot( t, T_measured, label='data')
plt.plot( t, a * np.sin( ( t - b ) / c ) + d, label='best fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

